# Deny-all security descriptor

Tags: c++, security, winapi

I'm trying to create a security descriptor to **deny everybody**. I'm currently doing this:

```
PSID pEveryoneSID = NULL;
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthWorld = SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthWorld, 1, SECURITY_WORLD_RID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &pEveryoneSID); // Creates SID that applies to everyone

EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;
ea.grfAccessPermissions = 0; // No permissions
ea.grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
ea.grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
ea.Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
ea.Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)pEveryoneSID;
// (Code from microsoft docs)
```

I'm just simply creating an `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` structure that applies to **everybody**, but also **denys** everybody due to the `0` for the `grfAccessPermissions` field.

This seems to work for everybody, even if I run a process that has `SYSTEM` privilege. No access is granted.

However, I was wondering if this is the correct way to go about this? Is it possible for some process or thing to **not** fall under `SECURITY_WORLD_RID`? If a process doesn't fall under `SECURITY_WORLD_RID`, then what would happen?

Comment: I think the docs imply that everyone and everything falls under SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY and SECURITY_WORLD_RID.

Comment: you need set empty DACL simply